# How to get strings from String array for use in SQL Query

Tags: java, android

Hi so i'm having an issue getting strings from a String array and the adding to SQL UPDATE statement. I've attemted to loop through and get the individual strings out but that doesn't really work as sql.updates 4th argument is an string array.  A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.. Thanks

this is the full query at present

```
update LOCK_PLAN_CHANGE ITEM_DOOR_ID=5 ID=50494 FLAG=0 TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID=1 KEY_SERIAL=15 ITEM_DOOR_ID=? [Ljava.lang.String;@b1b0936
```

ITEM_DOOR_ID is incorrect, it should be a number.

Code:

```
  public void pushUpdate(String table, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {


        SQLiteDatabase sql = getDatabaseHandler().getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHandler.DB_PASSWD);

            try {

                Log.i("_eLOQ", "SQL  insert");
                sql.update(table, values, where, whereArgs);
            }catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.e("SQL EXCEPTION", ex.toString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: To begin with I'm not 100% sure you're getting the `SQL` syntax properly. It should look like something like this: `UPDATE table_name SET attribute=2, another='hello' WHERE id=23` and in the current state you're missing various keywords for it to be a proper syntax.

Don't forget that `whereArgs` is an array, and you're passing a reference to it that's why you're getting `? [Ljava.lang.String;@b1b0936`

Comment: Thanks @SomerandomITboy, that was very helpful.  It took quite a lot of work but I managed to resolve my issues